# Opencart post code / city in payment method tab of checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, opencart

How can i post data of shipping city or postcode in payment method tab in `Opencart` version 2.1.0.2

I want to restrict COD to certain cities.Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create custom table to store available post code. create text box for product list page and create button **check available** use ajax to check available .

First disable the add to cart button after check ajax is successful enable add to cat button.